# python pandas new row attached to last one in csv when using to_csv in append mode

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a new row to the data in a csv file.  While the data is added, instead of being inserted into the next row, it is added onto the end of the previous row.  My problem code currently looks like:

```
qlist = list(data)
entries = [response, 0,0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame([entries], columns=qlist)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

When this is run, the 'response' variable ends up in the same place as the last data value of the last row.  How do I append entries into a new row instead?

Comment: What objects are *data* and *response* and what is their structure (i.e., nested lists, dictionaries)?

Answer (score 0):

Although your code snippet doesn't make much sense, I think your question is interesting. If I'm understanding you correctly, you have (1) an existing csv file, and (2) some output from a code snippet that you would like to add to that csv file. But your new data is being added in the last row of the existing csv file, and not as a new row.

So what you're starting out with is something like this:

```
# Old data
col1,col2
1,3
2,4
```

Your code produces some new data:

```
#New Data
5,6
```

And when trying to append that to your old data, you end up with this

```
col1,col2
1,3
2,4,5,6
```

But what you want is this:

```
col1,col2
1,3
2,4
5,6
```

If that is correct, you should load your existing data into a pandas dataframe, append the data there, and then overwrite your old csv file or produce a new one.

If you have a csv file with the old data above, you can do it like this:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd

# read existing data
df_old = pd.read_csv('C:/old.csv')

# Assign new data to a list.
# Note that the new data is written up as
# a list in the first element of a another list.
# Hence the double brackets.
# This way, the data is added as a row.
# If you use single brackets, pandas interprets
# the data as a column when added to a dataframe.
newData = [[5,6]]

# get column names of your existing data
colNames = df_old.columns

# make dataframe of new data that can be
# easily appended to your old data
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=newData, columns=colNames)

# concatenate old and new
df_complete = pd.concat([df_old, df_new], axis = 0)

# write your complete dataset to a new csv.
df_complete.to_csv('data_new.csv', index=False)
```

Now you should end up with your complete dataset in a csv file like so:

```
col1,col2
1,3
2,4
5,6
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if not and I'll have a look at it again.